# How to define timeout for copy image from server

Tags: php, copy

I need to copy an image from a server in order to create different types of images from it, like e.g. a thumbnail.

while it works ok with `ImageCreateFromJPEG($picture_location);` it will also create a problem if the image is not available and take 30s to timeout.

Therefore I thought about downloading first with copy:

```
copy('http://www.server.com/file.jpg', '/tmp/file.jpeg');
```

Unfortunatelly there is also no way to decrease timeout if the connect fails or the image has been removed.

Is there a better way to achieve what I am intending? Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) gives you the possibility to specify timeouts.

Answer (score 3):

You can download file via curl which has timeout option.

```
<?php

$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50); //timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Good idea. Is there also a way to skip timout if the url returns a 401 code?

Comment: 1) You can do two requests. First request without downloading any data (curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD'); or CURLOPT_NOBODY) and compare the code. Optionally second request for download.

2) You can write own WRITEFUNCTION (check manual) which in first call will test the code. But i have no idea to stop downloading in correct way.